# Delphi changing main form

Tags: delphi

I have this kind of problem. I'm trying to change my main form. I created new project and deleted main form and after that I added form to project using Project -> Add to project. And after that it automatically changes project settings and it is using added form. But if I run this application it shows empty form anyway even it is not empty form which I added to project.

```
program LimitMac;

uses
FMX.Forms,
MacLimiter in 'MacLimiter.pas' {FormLimiter};

{$R *.res}

begin
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TFormLimiter, FormLimiter);
Application.Run;
end.
```

and that MacLimiter (TFormLimiter) is my old form which I added to project but it shows empty form.

And MacLimiter unit this is part of MacLimiter unit and it shows that it is not empty form:

```
unit MacLimiter;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Edit, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox;

type
  TFormLimiter = class(TForm)
  StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
  Brush1: TBrushObject;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Label2: TLabel;
  EditTunnus: TEdit;
  EditSalasana: TEdit;
  ImageControl1: TImageControl;
  ImageControl2: TImageControl;
ListBox1: TListBox;
Label3: TLabel;
RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
RadioButton2: TRadioButton;
RadioButton3: TRadioButton;
RadioButton5: TRadioButton;
RadioButton6: TRadioButton;
RadioButton7: TRadioButton;
RadioButton8: TRadioButton;
RadioButton9: TRadioButton;
ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
Label4: TLabel;
Label5: TLabel;
Label6: TLabel;
Label7: TLabel;
Label9: TLabel;
Label10: TLabel;
Button1: TButton;
Button2: TButton;
Button3: TButton;
ListBox2: TListBox;
RadioButton4: TRadioButton;
RadioButton10: TRadioButton;
Label8: TLabel;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure EditSalasanaTyping(Sender: TObject);
procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton1Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton2Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton3Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton9Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton5Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton6Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton7Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure RadioButton8Change(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  FormLimiter: TFormLimiter;
var Index: Integer;
implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFormLimiter.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
   ProgressBar1.Value := 0;
   ProgressBar1.Max := 100;
   Button1.Enabled := false;

   for i := 0 to 100 do
   begin
     ProgressBar1.Value := i;
     Sleep(200);

     Application.ProcessMessages;
 end;
 Label9.Visible := true;
 Label10.Visible := true;
 Button3.Visible := true;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.EditSalasanaTyping(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
   if(index > 0) then begin
     Button2.Enabled := true;
   end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 0;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 1;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 2;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton3Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 3;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton5Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 5;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton6Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 6;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
 end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton7Change(Sender: TObject); 
begin
   index := 7;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton8Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   index := 8;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
    end;
end;

procedure TFormLimiter.RadioButton9Change(Sender: TObject); 
begin
   index := 9;
   if(EditTunnus.Text <> '') then begin
     if(EditSalasana.Text <> '') then begin
       Button2.Enabled := true;
     end;
   end;
 end;

end.
```

Comment: Please show code. Specifically that in the .dpr file.

Comment: now there is part of MacLimiter code and project file code

Comment: Is the .dfm file valid?

Comment: .dfm file is valid and there is only one MacLimiter.dfm and MacLimiter.pas in my filesystem. There is definitions of my form.

Comment: I guess you need to show a complete program

Comment: here it is the complete code of my application

Comment: @user3621674 You say the .dfm is valid, but your .pas file is using `{$R *.fmx}` resource. Is this correct? Perhaps show the content of your .fmx/.dfm

Comment: I removed two components and suddenly it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're simply using the default way of creating your forms:

These are created at the bottom of your `.DPR` file using `Application.CreateForm()`. Delphi will treat the first form created in this way as your "main form". If your intended main form is not first, simply move the line up.

If you're still having trouble, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23593495/edit) and add the contents of your `.DPR` between:

```
begin
  //
end.
```

---

**EDIT** Based on your edit, the above does not apply to you, but I'll leave it in place for anyone else who has a similar problem.

I suspect your "correct" `MacLimiter` form is in a different folder. Your `.DPR` is using the old one that's in the same folder as the `.DPR` (based on the following line):

```
MacLimiter in 'MacLimiter.pas' {FormLimiter};
```

All you really need to do is correct the path reference in the above line. E.g.:

```
MacLimiter in '..\CorrectFolder\MacLimiter.pas' {FormLimiter};
```

However, I sugest you also go back and delete the incorrect `.PAS` and `.DFM` files from the file system.

---

**EDIT 2** As [David suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593495/delphi-changing-main-form#comment36214035_23593495) your `DFM` might be invalid.

`PAS` and `DFM` files share a close relationship. The `DFM` file describes the layout of the form along with all its components. The `PAS` provides fields that will link to these components so that you can write code that referes to them.

So even though your `PAS` extract lists a number of components: if these aren't also defined within the `DFM`, then they're nothing but uninstantiated class fields.

So check that your `DFM` file actually contains these components.